# Problem apk Installation in android devices programmatically

Tags: android, apk

```
private void installNewApk(String outputFile) {

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(outputFile + "app-demo-debug.apk"));
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    install.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, true);
    install.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(install);
}
```

My apk is not corrupted file because manually my apk install but programmatically not install.
Unknown Source already allow

please provide the answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my problem  solved today